# Blender not showing objects in render?

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine, camera

I'm rendering an animation and I've got a peculiar problem. It seems like Blender is rendering in chunks.

At one moment in the render, there's just a bit of the objects visible.
But then at about frame 40, everything else pops in. I am using the Blender renderer

I am not quite sure how to explain it, so here is an example:
http://stepperman.me/weird_render.mp4

It's just a camera moving forward. So I'm not quite sure what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Oh. There was a huge cube in the center that was invisible for some reason, but nothing renders behind it. Very weird. I removed the cube and it was fixed.

Comment: You should probably accept your own answer, so that others know it is closed.